# How to find where error come from in snapshot.error?

Tags: flutter

I try to use `StreamBuilder` and I handle error by throw snapshot.error

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        throw snapshot.error!; <- This line
      }
    }
  },
);
```

But It tell that `This line` is the one making error.

Is there any way to see where actual error come from?

Comment: and what do you see if you `print(snapshot.error)`?

Comment: @pskink same as throwing it. In my case I/flutter ( 4878): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: Share you code for `stream`

Comment: @Josteve Sorry, but it a very huge code and company secret. Why would you want to see it?

Comment: Oh, the error seems to be coming from the `stream`.

Comment: @Josteve yes, it coming from there. My point is I want to know where it coming from. In debug console, it just say it coming from where I throw snapshot.error

Comment: sorry i meant https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/stackTrace.html, not `error`